# css background-image nav - not clickable

Tags: css

The mouse cursor doesn't indiciate clickability on this for some reason. It'll show the pointer for maybe a small section of it, but I'd like for the entire section to be clickable and obvious to user.

The icons show up correctly and look good, just aren't obviously clickable.

```
<ul class="team-icons">
    <li><a href="/link-url/" class="main-sprite header-icon header-team1"><span style="width:25px;height:25px;"></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="/link-url/" class="main-sprite header-icon header-team2"></a></li>
</ul>

.team-icons li {
 float: left;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 margin:5px 15px;
}
.header-icon {
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
display:inline-block;
background-size:375px; 
}
.header-team1 {
 background-position: -0 -93.75px;
}
.header-team2 {
 background-position: -25px -93.75px;   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `<li>` to display inline-block and the `<a>` to display block:

```
.team-icons li {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  margin:5px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.header-icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
}
```

This way the link takes up the entire space and the list item still is inline.

Edit: also you don't need the `float: left;` in the `li` if you are doing inline-block.

Comment: I did that. When I do an inspect, it's showing the link taking up the entire space. When I click it, it seems to click. However, the mouse doesn't look like a pointer (indicating it should be click-able). It's like only a small part of the overall space triggers the cursor change. Strange. Any idea?

Comment: Is there some other css that is changing the cursor? Here is a working implementation: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dvLMEd

Comment: Interestingly, i'm getting same behavior on your example. When the mouse enters the space, it flickers to a cursor, then goes back to typical pointer. I'm on Chrome.

Comment: Are you talking about the space between the elements? The red part should all be a pointer.

Comment: If i move mouse over from white into the red block, it goes from regular point, flickers to the "click pointer" then immediately goes back to regular opinter the entire time its in red. I checked this on Safari too and got same behavior.

Comment: That is not normal behavior. Try this codepen on a different computer if you can.